# Saving a text as rtf using a RichtTextBox

Tags: .net, vb.net, file-io, richtextbox, rtf

I have a vb2010 application and want to save the text as a rtf document.

I do as follow:

```
Dim rtb As New RichTextBox
rtb.Text = "something"
rtb.SaveFile(myfile)
```

but the file is saved as an empty rtf document.

If I repeat the savefile line (line 3) again, it works and I get my rtf file document exactly as it should be.

Here the "working" code:

```
Dim rtb As New RichTextBox
rtb.Text = "something"
rtb.SaveFile(myfile)
rtb.SaveFile(myfile)
```

in other words it is like that the first SaveFile (line 3) instruction initialize the RichtTextBox and the next line (line 4) save the file.

Something is wrong, but I cannot find anything in those only 3 lines of code! Any suggestion? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I advice you to get RTF from the property 'Rtf' and save it to file manually, for example in C#

(sorry I'm C# programmer, not VB):

```
        RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
        rtb.Text = "Something";
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"d:\Something.rtf", rtb.Rtf);
```

Comment: WriteAllText worked, but I had to use the overload 
`WriteAllText(path As String, contents As String, encoding As System.Text.Encoding)` in order to get the right encoding.
Moreover I could not load the rtf file just using rtf.LoadFile, but I had to use the overload  
`rtfTxt.LoadFile(sFilename,RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)`.
Without the streamtype I get always an invalid file type error.

Thank you anyway, but I still do not understand why my first code did not work

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
Application.DoEvents();
```

before

```
rtb.SaveFile(myfile)
```